# slow php xdebug on VirtualBox ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug

I am trying to xdebug php, everything works fine but answers are very slow (1-2 minutes).

PS: I am debugging YII framework project.

Any ideas?

Comment: xdebug + frameworks (a lot of 'abstraction') usually equals a lot of performance loss. You may try to disable some functionality in it's settings, but there is a reason why it shouldn't be on production servers.

Comment: It should be pretty fast unless you have profiling turned on, eg you have `xdebug.profiler_enable = 1` set in your .ini file.

Comment: I can confirm this, using VirtualBox (Ubuntu) even with `xdebug.profiler_enable = 0` on the configuration. Seems to be a bug filed [here](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=765). And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677388/xdebug-really-slow) is a related issue.

Comment: Had this problem. What worked for me: ensure you can ping your host from the guest (I use host-only adapter conf), if not probably because of your firewall ; ensure the field xdebug.remote_host is set to your host ip in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini.