# Netbeans Apache Conflict

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using Netbeans 8.0 to debug WordPress plugins using Xammp 1.8.3 for local development.

Everything works great independently, i.e. I can call up the Xampp info page via browser navigation to localhost. From there I can launch PhpMyAdmin, etc. and I don't encounter any problems.

I can also debug my plugin projects from within Netbeans and, again, no problems.

However, when I'm debugging a project, any attempt to access the Xampp info page or PhpMyAdmin fails. If I launch PhpMyAdmin first, and then try to debug the project, PhpMyAdmin is bounced from its session and will not work again until I've finished debugging. Also, in cases like this, the debugger will often switch from the project I am debugging to one of the files of whatever activity I was performing in PhpMyAdmin. For example, if I was monitoring MySQL performance, the debugger will load server_status_monitor.php and stop at the fist line, exactly as if was starting to debug that code instead.

In other words, Netbeans seems to be trying to debug any calls to the server, and not just those from the project I"m trying to debug.

To counter this, I setup virtual hosts so that I can access Xampp via localhost and my project via a custom server name, but this has not fixed my problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the answer to this question in this thread: [enabling xdebug remote debug makes apache server very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736304/enabling-xdebug-remote-debug-makes-apache-server-very-slow)

Turns out, I needed to add these settings to my php.ini file:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart    = 0
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
```

And now I'm able to debug independently of other server requests.

I'm a bit of rookie when it comes to stackoverflow, but it seems any credit for answering this question should go to the fellow who answered the other one. Can I do that, and if so, anyone have a quick pointer on how?

Wayne