# Clicking 'Refresh' crashes phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

I recently updated my WAMP install from PHP 5.5 to 5.6 and started having issues with phpMyAdmin. Assuming it was just my outdated version of phpMyAdmin, I updated it to version 4.7.4, but the issue persists.

The problem is that when I click refresh in the toolbar in phpMyAdmin (not in my browser), it causes phpMyAdmin to completely freeze. This happens when I use most of the toolbar buttons or console. After checking the debugger, it looks like no response is ever sent from the server. I can click on column headers to order the page as normal and I can inline edit.

This doesn't affect any other apps running on my localhost. I'm able to access them and use them as normal, but I can't do anything with phpMyAdmin until I restart WAMP.

I'm not getting any errors in the `php_error.log` nor any other logs. Any ideas was could be causing this?

This is basically what's in my `mysql.log` over and over again:

```
2017-08-28 04:05:52 11128 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-08-28 04:05:52 11128 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-08-28 04:05:52 11128 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-08-28 04:05:52 11128 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-08-28 04:05:52 11128 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-08-28 04:05:52 11128 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-08-28 04:05:52 11128 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-08-28 04:05:52 11128 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-08-28 04:05:52 11128 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-08-28 04:05:52 11128 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-08-28 04:05:52 11128 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-08-28 04:05:52 11128 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 7435516915
2017-08-28 04:05:53 11128 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-08-28 04:05:53 11128 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-08-28 04:05:53 11128 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-08-28 04:05:53 11128 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-08-28 04:05:53 11128 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-08-28 04:05:53 11128 [Note] wampmysqld64: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.17-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] wampmysqld64: Arrêt normal du serveur

2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Binlog end
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-08-28 04:08:03 11128 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2017-08-28 04:08:04 11128 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 7435516941
2017-08-28 04:08:04 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2017-08-28 04:08:04 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2017-08-28 04:08:04 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2017-08-28 04:08:04 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-08-28 04:08:04 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2017-08-28 04:08:04 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-08-28 04:08:04 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2017-08-28 04:08:04 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2017-08-28 04:08:04 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2017-08-28 04:08:04 11128 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2017-08-28 04:08:04 11128 [Note] wampmysqld64: Arrêt du serveur terminé
```

After doing a query in the console, I checked the network tab to look at the requests. This is what they look like:

[image: headers panel]
[image: params panel]
[image: cookies panel]

All are blank, save the stacktrace that shows the javascript that triggered the request.

Comment: Any mysql or server logs?

Comment: What happens at 04:08:03 ? Is this the time when you click on Refresh in phpMyAdmin? or does the error occur even if you don't do anything? By the way, looks like phpMyAdmin is not crashing, it's waiting for the server.

Comment: That's when I restarted the server. I checked in the console and it appears that no data is being sent back from the server so maybe this is an Apache issue?

Comment: Check that your PHP config includes a timeout. I've seen this kind of thing happen when a script gets stuck in a loop or on a very long query and there's no timeout. (particularly on a WAMP stack installed locally on a PC for development). Better for it to timeout and throw an error than to lock up the server because it can't time out.

Comment: If all else fails, consider using an alternative tool -- I find [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) to be just as good as phpMyAdmin. In fact, I tend to use it in preference to phpMyAdmin because it's a lot easier to install and work with at a server level.

Comment: These are very short queries that shouldn't take a second to complete. It looks like anything to do with ajax doesn't work.

Comment: Try clearing out any residual data in your browser (cookies etc) and restart it.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 Have you checked the memory usage on your MySQL? This used to happen to me when mine was hosted in an instance with small RAM available.

Comment: have you checked to try this in different browsers ? my firefox sometimes messes up things

Comment: Please show us the stopped request in network tab in browser. We see that it's some Post request, but I want to see all request headers, requested URL and request data (body)

Comment: Version of WAMP? I'm curious to reproduce it :)

Comment: OK I had the same problem when I upgraded Mysql to my Wamp. The cause of this problem is that I did not properly uninstall the previous version of mysql. Maybe that's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This situation could happen because you are using XDebug or another debugger**.

PHPMyAdmin is a PHP application, and if you have XDebug configured in a way that it picks up every PHP execution and stops at first line - it will be also triggered for PHPMyAdmin. And it will wait until you press "continue" or restart the server.

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736304/enabling-xdebug-remote-debug-makes-apache-server-very-slow), try to disable "remote_autostart" and "profiler_enable" modes:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
```

Or even comment out line where XDebug is enabled, if above does not help:

```
;zend_extension = "/absolute/path/to/your/xdebug-extension.so"
```

Comment: I've disabled xdebug and I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the $cfg['OBGzip'] directive to false in your config.inc.php file and the zlib.output_compression directive to Off in your php configuration file.

Source: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html

If not, try following the troubleshoot steps in that page.

Hope it helps.