# Symfony terribly slow : 30 seconds

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have a new computer, Dell Inspiron 17 7000 Series. This is Laptop :

- i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2601 MHz
- 16 Go RAM
- 512 Mo SSD
- Windows 10, Wampserver 3.0.6 and PHP7 and OPCache

But with Symfony (New app, juste 3 slim controllers), my app is terribly slow ... 30 seconds :/

This is my `php.ini` var :

```
 - realpath_cache_size = 12288K
 - realpath_cache_ttl = 1800
 - opcache.max_accelerated_files=60000
```

Can you help me ?

[image]

Comment: Can you try to run server with php bin/console server:start and than check execution time ?

Comment: It is faster, ~3/4 seconds :)

Comment: It's ok for dev mode. So problem is in wamp server.

Comment: Because it is Windows, I suggest you use Linux.

Comment: Your var directory might be on a shared drive?  Not doing anything fancy with vagrant or docker or vm's?  My machine, which is considerably less powerful, easily delivers pages in less than 1 second in development mode.  I happen to use xampp but that should not make a real difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably it's because of enabled XDebug.
It happens with many PHP applications on Windows, not only with Symfony.

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736304/enabling-xdebug-remote-debug-makes-apache-server-very-slow), try to disable "remote_autostart" and "profiler_enable" modes:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
```

Or even comment out line where XDebug is enabled, if above does not help:

```
;zend_extension = "/absolute/path/to/your/xdebug-extension.so"
```